# Reize v-app-bar to match navigation drawer item Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm adding like a page header using the `v-app-bar` inside the `v-content` and `v-container`, it looks good but I would like to change the height in order to match the nav drawer on the left. This is what it looks like, as you can see the app bar is shorter than the user info part of the nav drawer. Is there a way to "match" the height?

[image]

This is the app-bar code

```
<v-app-bar absolute fixed color="white" elevate-on-scroll>
    <h2 style="color: #6cb2eb">Categories</h2>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-btn depressed color="primary" dark @click="createItem">New</v-btn>
</v-app-bar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of v-app-bar using the height props. By default, the height is 60. If you set to 80 or something, the issue will be fixed.

```
<v-app-bar absolute fixed color="white" elevate-on-scroll height="80">
    <h2 style="color: #6cb2eb">Categories</h2>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-btn depressed color="primary" dark @click="createItem">New</v-btn>
</v-app-bar>
```